# How to use the option selected in options_for_select in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu, controller

I have this dropdown in my Rails application:

```
<%= select_tag(:report_id, options_for_select([["Summary1", 7], ["Summary2", 6]])) %>
```

The user selectes a value from the dropdown above and clicks aon a button shown below to generate a PDF :

```
<%= link_to 'Generate', pdf_path(format: :pdf, report: :report_id), class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

This is my controller function that gets called when the button above is clicked:

```
def show
  init_report_data
  respond_to do |format, report|
    format.html
    format.pdf do
      puts "***************** report id" + report.to_s + "*************************"
      case report 
      when 7
        report_name = 'summary1'
      when 6
        report_name = 'summary2'
      end

      render pdf:         "Forecast Report",
           template:    "forecast/" + report_name + ".html.erb",
           disposition: "attachment",
           :page_width  => '18in',
           :page_height => '15in'
    end
  end
end
```

The controller function gets called fine but the value of the parameter "report" comes up empty inside the above controller function.

What am I doing wrong here? Please help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<%= form_tag forecast_report_pdf_path do %>
  <%= select_tag(:report_id, options_for_select([["Summary1", 7], ["Summary2", 6]])) %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :format, :pdf %>
  <%= submit_tag("Generate Report") %>
<% end %>
```

This code worked. Thanks much for your inputs!

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you're not using a form here.

Use form_tag and keep the `select_tag` inside the `form_tag`.

Also, You will have to replace `link_to` with a `submit` button. Don't forget to include the below line inside the form to make the request to respond with `pdf` format.

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :format, :pdf %>
```

The reason is the `link_to` tag don't pass your `select_tag` value or any other field value. In this scenario, you've to use `form` and there is no other option to it.

Or use JavaScript to replace the `id` in `url` when the select option changes. Since You're trying to get the show action I assume you need to pass the id in `path`.

Comment: Hi @abhilashreddy

I added a form and converted link_to to button_to:


`    <div class="form-group" style="width:40%">
         
      <%= form_tag({}, {:method => :get}) do %>
        <%= select_tag(:report_id, options_for_select([["Summary1", 7], ["Summary2", 6]])) %>
      <% end %>

    </div>
    
    <div style="padding-left: 10px;margin-top: -52px;"  >
      <%= button_to 'Generate Report',forecast_report_pdf_path(format: :pdf, report: :report_id), class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
    </div>`

But still no luck! Pls help!

Comment: seems like you didn't specify the path for the form. it should be something like this <%= form_tag do_some_things_path, method: :get do %>

Comment: <%= form_tag forecast_report_pdf_path do %>
         <%= select_tag(:report_id, options_for_select([["Summary1", 7], ["Summary2", 6]])) %>
         <%= hidden_field_tag :format, :pdf %>
         <%= submit_tag("Generate Report") %>

This code worked. Thanks much for your inputs!